# TypeScript: Pixi.js types with 'none' Module Settings

Tags: javascript, typescript, pixi.js

I have a 100% JS project that runs in the browser with about 20 JS files or so that have all function names in the global scope. Currently I can just modify a JS file and refresh and immediately see the change.

However, I would like the benefits of static type checking; enter TypeScript. I added type annotations to variables and functions and set `module` to `none`. This works well! `tsc` will read in the .ts, do type checking, and then emit the same .js I had previously which I can run in-browser with no modifications.

The problem is when I want to integrate with a 3rd party library. In my case, `pixi.js`.

If I try to do something like `let x = PIXI.settings.TARGET_FPMS;`, then tsc complains `Cannot find name 'PIXI'`. I tried adding `/// <reference path="pixi.min.js"/>`, and while the path resolves, it still can't find the name.

Solutions online suggest I do `npm install pixi.js` and then `import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'`. However, if I do that, I can no longer use the `none` module setting which means now I have to put import and export statements everywhere, which means the emitted .js files now have browser-incompatible `require` or `import` statements, which means now I need webpack or something to get rid of those, etc... the complexity is ballooning.

Is there a way have TypeScript access pixi.js type information *without* all the import/export/modules/webpack business? Basically I just want `tsc` to check that the shape of things is correct without radically changing the current app architecture.

Barring that, it seems like the only solution is to add: `declare var PIXI: any;` somewhere in the file.

Comment: "browser-incompatible `import` statements" [Pretty sure a lot of modern browsers handle `import`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_statements_import)...

Comment: @HereticMonkey the other problem is that I do have a really simple bundler - basically just `cat *.js > bundle.js`. This is extremely fast (a few ms) and simple compared to npm bundlers. If I use `import` I'm pretty sure I will no longer be able to do that and will need to integrate webpack or something to accomplish the same thing and much more slowly at that. Basically I want to avoid having to change a bazillion files to start using import/export syntax + webpack integration just to get pixi type info

Comment: Bundlers are *still* extremely fast: do you really care if it's at most 100 ms slower? I don't know why you aren't using one of the more conventional bundlers... It's not like you're adding an extra build step; you're replacing your existing one.

Comment: I don't care if it's 100ms slower, but I do care about the complexity costs that converting everything to import/export/bundler will introduce to the project. Currently everything is plain html, js, and css. I'd like to keep it that way as long as possible. My current use case of TypeScript basically just converts all the .ts to .js in a way that allows me to continue to use plain html, css, and js without a bunch of esoteric npm tools encumbering development

Comment: So don't bundle; keep everything as separate files. Use HTTP/2 on the server; it's much better at providing multiple files to the browser at once such that bundling is less important. Combine that with native module loading and it's "plain HTML, JS, and CSS".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an [HN post](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=33055380):

> Here is a minimum "repro" of your use case:
> tsconfig.json

```
{
  "include": ["index.d.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

> index.d.ts

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'

declare global {
  interface Window {
    PIXI: typeof PIXI
  }
}
```

> index.ts

```
console.log(window.PIXI)
```

> There is still an import but because it is in the .d.ts file it won't
> be included in the runtime code.